# Compiling PHP5.6.24 on Centos5.11

Tags: php, c++, shell, centos5

I am trying to install php5.6.24 on centos5.11 I am facing problem when I try to configure it with --enable-intl it gives me
`configure: error: Don't know how to define struct flock on this system, set --enable-opcache=no`
when I try to configure it with --disable-opcache it configures just fine but when I try to make it gives me

`/php/php-5.6.24/ext/standard/basic_functions.c:3625: undefined reference to zm_startup_password`

`ext/standard/.libs/basic_functions.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x1168): undefined reference to zif_password_hash`

`ext/standard/.libs/basic_functions.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x1188): undefined reference to zif_password_get_info`

`ext/standard/.libs/basic_functions.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x11a8): undefined reference to zif_password_needs_rehash`

`ext/standard/.libs/basic_functions.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x11c8): undefined reference to zif_password_verify`

`/usr/local/lib/libicuio.so: undefined reference to std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)@GLIBCXX_3.4.9`

`/usr/local/lib/libicui18n.so: undefined reference to memcpy@GLIBC_2.14`

`/usr/local/lib/libicui18n.so: undefined reference to __cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length@CXXABI_1.3.8`

`collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1`

does anyone know how can I make it work with --enable-intl

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error outputs during build on cygwin regarding the undefined references. I installed the libcrypt-devel package and re-run the configure script after perform 'make distclean'.

For the first error message regarding the struct flock type I have no hint, but in CentOS this is defined in /usr/include/bits/fcntl.h, which is included in /usr/include/fcntl.h. Maybe this helps a little bit.